# OracleBulkCopy ORA-26041 Error Leap Year in 1932

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, date

Loading data from a SQL Server query that contains birth dates. One of them happens to be 2/29/1932. When importing the data to an Oracle server via `OracleBulkCopy`, I get the `ORA-26041` error. All other dates including leap year dates work except for 1932. Switching to an insert statement instead of `OracleBulkCopy` works fine. Date value directly out of the DataTable = '2/29/1932 12:00:00 AM'.  The field has the `Date` data type in both SQL Server and Oracle.

Using `Oracle.DataAccess` 4.121.1.0 + .NET 4.5 x64 + Windows 7 + VS2012

Code:

```
... 
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, myConnectionString)) {
        da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        da.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
        da.FillSchema(myDataset, SchemaType.Source, "MyDataTable");
        da.Fill(myDataset, "MyDataTable");
}

var clientInfo = OracleGlobalization.GetClientInfo();
clientInfo.DateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM";
clientInfo.TimeStampFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM";
clientInfo.Language = "AMERICAN";

OracleGlobalization.SetThreadInfo(clientInfo);

var setDateFormatCommand = new OracleCommand("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'", objConn);
setDateFormatCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

var setTimeStampFormatCommand =
        new OracleCommand("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'", objConn);
setTimeStampFormatCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

var setDateLanguageCommand =
        new OracleCommand("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN", objConn);
setDateLanguageCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

using (var bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(objConn)) {
        bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 20000;
        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100000;
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(myDataset.Tables["MyDataTable"]);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a fluke with the installation of ODP.NET.  I installed the latest version 12.1.0.2.1  32 and 64 bit of ODP.NET which happened to come out on the same day as the question was posted 12/23/2014.  This resolved the issue.